# Phpmydirectory - remove extra query string in 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In phpmydirectory framework, I'm trying to redirect old page URL to new page URL using `.htaccess` 301 redirect.

ex: `http://example.com/pages/newurl.html?id=old-friendly-url`

Redirect works but at the end of new URL, old friendly URL is concatenated as id.

How can I avoid that?

```
RewriteRule ^pages\/(.+)\.html$ page.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
Redirect 301 /pages/features.html /pages/ost-to-pst-ost-to-office365-ost-to-exchange-migrator.‌html?
```

Comment: show us your .htaccess file?

Comment: Or, specifically, show your current redirect. Depending on the method currently used to perform the redirect, you'll either need to add just a single character or rewrite the directive using a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /pages/features.html /pages/ost-to-pst-ost-to-office365-ost-to-exchange-migrator.‌html?
> ```

Presumably this is the redirect in question? If it already contains a `?` at the end then the query string on the original request should already be getting removed - however, if using a mod_alias `Redirect` you will end up with a trailing `?` on the target URL.

You should use mod_rewrite instead to perform this redirect. Since you are already using mod_rewrite for internal rewrites, this is recommended in order to avoid potential conflicts.

Your original redirect is not checking the query string, so I presume this is not a required - you only need to match the URL-path.

The following redirect should go *before* your existing internal rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/oldurl\.html$ /pages/newurl.html? [R,L]
```

The trailing `?` on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* removes the query string from the request. Alternatively, use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+